# I am not able to access x:Name of controls in ListView in XAML and Code behind

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.listview

I have a ListView in Xamarin forms which has a custom cell in it. The custom cell contains an Image control with a x:Name attribute. Now I tried to bind an activity indicator IsRunning Property to the Image IsLoading Property and Xamarin forms could not find the Image using the x:Name. I tried accessing from the backend too, same thing.

I added other elements in the Listview and their x:Name were not visible too.

NB: I can access x:Name of controls I put outside the ListView so it is looking like a listview issue.

```
<StackLayout>
    <ActivityIndicator x:Name="activity" Color="Purple" HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="50" IsRunning="{Binding Source={x:Reference Offerimg},Path=IsLoading}"></ActivityIndicator>


    <ListView x:Name="OfferLV" HasUnevenRows="True" x:FieldModifier="Public" SeparatorVisibility="None" BackgroundColor="White">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell >
                    <StackLayout Padding="0,10,0,10">
                        <Image  x:Name="offerimg" HeightRequest="500" WidthRequest="100" Aspect="AspectFill"></Image>
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: I don't find it a good idea to have name inside ViewCell. You might want to have ClassId or StyleId instead and bind it to a property so you can access them easier later on.

Comment: Thanks but I am not sure how to do that. Do you have any documentation I can refer to ?

Comment: What do you mean by `Image IsLoading Property` ? There is no such property on the Image control. I don't understand what you want to achieve. Is it that when ActivityIndicator IsRunning == true, you want your image to disappear or to show up ?

Comment: @Umar3x I want my activity indicator IsRunning to be true when my image Is loading and let it disappear once the image appears. How can I do that please ?

Comment: Do you load your image as a resource in your project or from an Uri ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a very nice library [FFImageLoading](https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading) that will help you do what you want, and has a built in `IsLoading` property to display an `ActivityIndicator` accordingly. You can also handles loading error and so ...

```
<ListView VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Grid>
                            <ff:CachedImage x:Name="Image" Source="https://www.allibert-trekking.com/uploads/media/images/thumbnails/AMin3_10-photo-montagne-chine-lac.jpeg?v2" />
                            <ActivityIndicator Color="OrangeRed" IsRunning="{Binding IsLoading}" IsVisible="{Binding IsLoading}" BindingContext="{x:Reference Name=Image}" />
                        </Grid>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

I created a sample for this example here : https://github.com/vincentcastagna/ImageLoadingPlaceHolder

Answer (score 1):

That's how things are expected to work in XAML technologies including Xamarin.Forms.

There is not just a single `ViewCell`, but there could be thousands of them and you can't access thousands different items with one name.

Recommended way is to use data binding. Frequently you can also access those items by casting the `sender` in events.

Comment: Thanks but is do you have any documentation I can refer to? I'm not sure how to go about that

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data-binding-basics

Comment: Thanks for the documentation. I went through the documentation and it turned out it was exactly what i was trying to do before. If i have to bind from the markup, i still have to reference the x:name of the source control. And the problem is that i cannot access any control I put in the DataTemplate of the ListView via their x:name. Is there any way to solve that? and that is clearly what the problem is right now. If you have any other solution, kindly proffer them to me,

Comment: I decided to delete my comment as it sounded a bit arrogant, but to rephrase it - what you said above isn't correct which means you've got a lot of to learn. There is the sample there exactly with the ListView, check it carefully and you'll realize how you should do it.